# Prepopulating an email message using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application which displays a list of users , When clicking on the email button I want the email client to open up with a prepopulated message ( I make the message using javascript) , I am not sure about how to prepopulate the message

Any help would be appreciated

I would post snippets , but honestly I dnt know how to start with this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[URI encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the text and then append it to a `mailto:` URL:

```
<a href='mailto:person@place.com?body=text%20here'>Send mail!</a>
```

More generally, you can use:

- subject
- body (multiple `body` parameters will put each on a new line)
- CC
- BCC

with an ampersand (&) between each pair.

```
mailto:person@place.com?subject=Hi&body=some%20text
```

Comment: hey Thank you for this , If I had to add an subject I would assume it would be something like this    <a href='mailto:person@place.com?subject='text+here'?body=text+here'>Send mail!</a>

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to find all the links that have `mailto:`, then process their href to add the message body:

```
$("a[href^='mailto:']").prop( "href", function(i, prop){
     return prop + "?body=" + encodeURIComponent( "Your message here" );
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/6qXrU/

Comment: The question was "Using Javascript", so I feel like this is a good answer.